# Blender Batch Rename Collections not working?

Tags: error, collections, outliner

i want to Batch Rename multiple selected Collections. But it does not work. I get a message "Rename 0 Collections". With Objects it is working fine. What am i doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: You appear to be trying to replace 'Vase 1' with 'Vase 1'.  That would result in 0 renames.  Did you mean something else?

Answer (score 3):

Cursor should be in the outliner then you press <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, so that Blender knows, that you want to run this command in the outliner, not in the 3D viewport.

Comment: IDK if your hotkey is set differently but I think the default shortcut for batch rename is Ctrl+F2. Alt+F3 does nothing for me.

Comment: Yep. thanks for pointing that